# How to input values in a multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have

```
main(){...
float **tree;   
//How to set some values here for e.g. If I want tree to be a 15x2 array of some values?
reprVectorsTree *r1 = new reprVectorsTree(tree,8,2);
...}

reprVectorsTree(float **tree, int noOfReprVectors, int dimensions)
{.....
```

How to use malloc here so that I can set some data inside the tree array?

Comment: Just like your old question, you should tag this properly as C++.

Comment: You use `new` in the code but ask for usage of `malloc`. What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allocate memory for `tree`, try something like:

```
float** tree;
tree = (float**)malloc(15 * sizeof(float*));
for(i = 0; i < 15; i++) 
    tree[i] = (float*)malloc(2 * sizeof(float));
```

Now you can set values:

```
for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        tree[i][j] = 2;
```

Don't forget to `free` it later, although I don't understand why you are combining `new` and `malloc` together?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the `tree` variable you want to allocate for.

You can do like this:

```
float **tree;

// Allocate 15 "arrays"
tree = new float*[15];

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    // Allocate a new "array" of two floats
    tree[i] = new float[2];

    // Fill the newly allocated floats with "random" data
    tree[i][0] = 1.0;
    tree[i][1] = 2.0;
}
```

However, if it's possible I would recommend that you change the `reprVectorsTree` object to accept `std::vector< std::vector< float > >` instead.